# Assignment to Multiple Variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, destructuring

#### Can properties of an object somehow be assigned to multiple variables in JavaScript with a single call (for convenience)?

```
function getValues() {
    return {
        first: 1,
        second: 2
    };
}

function convenientAssignment() {
    let first = 0;
    let second = 0;
    {first, second} = getValues(); // <-- How can this be achieved?
    console.log("Values:", first, second);
}
```

Without using separate assignments like the following:

```
let values = getValues();
first = values.first;
second = values.second;
```

**This question has nothing to do with concurrency.**

Comment: Why do you need this?  Is it because of some (perceived) concurrency problem, or just for convenience?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just conveniency. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, Use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get an objects values into variables.

```
function simultaneous() {
    const {first, second} = getValues(); // <-- et voila!
    console.log("Values:", first, second);
}
```

In your example, where your variables were already declared, you can do:

```
function convenientAssignment() {
    let first = 0;
    let second = 0;
    ({first, second} = getValues()); // <-- et voila!
    console.log("Values:", first, second);
}
```

Comment: What if the variables have been declared before, for example class members?

Comment: Thank you! Great! It was difficult to google this.. Now I know it is called *object destructuring*.

Answer (score 3):

This is pretty much what a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Basic_assignment) is supposed to do:

```js
function getValues() {
    return {
        first: 1,
        second: 2
    };
}

let { first, second } = getValues();

console.log( first, second );
// 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In your particular case since you've already declared first and second you need to wrap the descructuring assignment in brackets () like so:

```
function getValues() {
    return {
        first: 1,
        second: 2
    };
}

function convenientAssignment() {
    let first = 0;
    let second = 0;
    ({first, second} = getValues()); // <-- Note the (...)
    console.log("Values:", first, second);
}
```

Because `{first, second}` by itself is considered a block.